# Why does my simple neural network loss function is noisy gradually as the program runs backpropagation algorithm?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, neural-network

I'm currently working on creating my own neural network library in Python 3.10.6, and everything was going on until the backpropagation part. I'm not absolutely sure about my backpropagation algorithm, and more than that, my gradient descent function. The loss estimations are extremely noisy, as you can see in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfpN7.png). I don't really understand why, and any help would be very great. I'm sorry for my long and unoptimized code...

```py
# Neural Network implementation

class DenseNetwork:
    def __init__(self, layer_lengths, input_length, activations=None, init_mode=None):
        self.layer_lengths = layer_lengths
        self.input_length = input_length
        self.activations = activations
        if self.activations is None:
            self.activations = array([relu] * len(self.layer_lengths))
        self.init_mode = init_mode
        if self.init_mode is None:
            self.init_mode = "random"
        
        if self.init_mode == "random":
            self.weights = [random.uniform(-1, 1, (current_len, in_len)) for current_len, in_len in zip(self.layer_lengths[:], [self.input_length] + self.layer_lengths[:-1])]
            self.biases = [random.uniform(-1, 1, (current_len, 1)) for current_len in self.layer_lengths[:]]
        
        self.layers = []
        for i in range(len(self.layer_lengths)):
            if i == 0:
                last = self.input_length
            else:
                last = self.layer_lengths[i-1]
            
            self.layers.append(DenseLayer(self.layer_lengths[i], last, self.activations[i], "set", self.weights[i], self.biases[i]))
        
    def forward(self, input, to=-1, activation=True): # activation here is enabling the last activation function
        last = input
        for l in self.layers[:to-1]:
            last = l(last)
        last = self.layers[-1](last, activation)
        return last
    
    def backward_weights(self, input, desired_out):
        e_out = deriv[self.activations[-1]](self.forward(input, -1, False)) * (self.forward(input) - desired_out)
        e = [e_out]
        for i in range(len(self.layer_lengths)-1, 0, -1):
            e.insert(0, deriv[self.activations[i]](self.forward(input, i, False)) * (dot(self.weights[i].T, e[0])))
        return [array((e_layer)) for e_layer in reversed(e)]
    
    def backward_biases(self, input, desired_out):
        e_out = deriv[self.activations[-1]](self.forward(input, -1, False)) * (self.forward(input) - desired_out)
        e = [e_out]
        for i in range(len(self.layer_lengths)-1, 0, -1):
            activation_derivative = deriv[self.activations[i]](self.forward(input, i, False))
            e.insert(0, activation_derivative * e[0])
        return [array(e_layer) for e_layer in reversed(e)]
    
    def grad_desc(self, input, desired_out, learning_rate=10**-3):
        e_w = self.backward_weights(input, desired_out)
        e_b = self.backward_biases(input, desired_out)
        
        for i in range(len(self.layer_lengths)):
            self.weights[i] = self.weights[i] - learning_rate * e_w[i]
            self.biases[i] = self.biases[i] - learning_rate * e_b[i]
    
    def eval_losses(self, input, desired_out):
        return linalg.norm(self.forward(input) - desired_out)/len(desired_out)
    
    def __call__(self, input, activation=True):
        return self.forward(input, activation)
```

I tried changing parameters such as learning rate, activation function, etc..., but nothing worked.

Comment: I think you forgot to load the image with the result. You should upload it, that may help people have a better understanding of your issue and offer a better help.

Comment: Try computing an approximate gradient by finite differences, and compare that to your computed gradient. This can show where the gradient is going wrong -- typically some of the terms are correct and some aren't. Try simplifying the network (e.g. 2 inputs and 1 output, no hidden layer) and get the gradient right, then start making it more complex, verifying results at each step.

Comment: Yes, it seems that the ilage didn't get uploaded, i'll edit my message this afternoon. And I will try as Robert said, I began a bit too fast.